# LARAVEL 5.5: Fetch unique values from database and pass to view as form select options

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking to fetch unique values from a table in my database and pass the company name into my view as options in a drop down list within a form.

The function in my controller looks like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $admin = Admin::find($id);
    $companies = DB::table('vacancies')->distinct()->select('company')->get()->toArray();
    return view('admin')->with('admin',$admin)->with('companies',$companies);
}
```

And my view looks like this:

```
<div class="form-group">
   @foreach ($companies as $company)
     {{ Form::label('Select Company')}}
     {{ Form::select('companies', $company->company, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Please select ...']) }}
   @endforeach
</div>
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

If I try {{dd($companies}} I can see an array is being passed through to the view OK. This array looks like this:

```
array:353[
  0 => {#274 ▼
  +"company": "Example company name"
  }......
]
```

Ditching the loop and reverting back to:

```
<div class="form-group">
  {{ Form::label('Select Company')}}
  {{ Form::select('companies', $companies, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Please select ...']) }}
</div>
```

causes another error to be thrown which states:

```
htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given
```

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: do you have companies in  `vacancies` table ?

Comment: Hi @rkj - yes, the table contains a column called 'company' which I'm fetching here: $companies = DB::table('vacancies')->distinct()->select('company')->get()->toArray();

Comment: then you can use `pluck`

Comment: Thanks @rkj - as per answers below, that's exactly what I needed to do so you were right!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your controller

```
public function index()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $admin = Admin::find($id);
    $companies = DB::table('vacancies')->distinct()->pluck('company')->toArray();
    return view('admin')->with('admin',$admin)->with('companies',$companies);
}
```

Comment: That's the one! Needed to pluck 'company' rather than get(). Thanks @Aakash Tushar

Answer (score 1):

Fllow as per below

your index function must be like below

```
public function index()
{
    $id = Auth::user()->id;
    $admin = Admin::find($id);
    $companies = DB::table('vacancies')->distinct()->pluck('company')->toArray();
    return view('admin')->with('admin',$admin)->with('companies',$companies);
}
```

your view must me like below

```
<div class="form-group">
     {{ Form::label('Select Company')}}
     {{ Form::select('companies', $companies, ['class'=>'form-control', 'placeholder'=>'Please select ...']) }}
</div>
```

let me know if any

Comment: Thanks Niraj, I changed get() to pluck('company', id'). This returned only the last entry, but ditching the 'id' as suggested by @Aakash Tushar returns the full list fine. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @NirajSavaliya just remove `->select('company')` and `id` from pluck. Actually you r code is fine generally we do `->pluck('company','id')` for `options` value and text, his requirement was different. anyway happy coding

Comment: @rkj
answer Modified,